# SVN deletes newly added directories during merge

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I'm developing a java application which leverages gradle for dependency management and SVN for version control in a windows environment. I also use the Eclipse IDE. I want to merge trunk into a working branch with SVN. I moved packages and files around in the working branch. When merging trunk into the working branch from the command line with the following command:

```
svn merge -r InitBranchRevision:FinalBranchRevision C:\DevTools\workspace\my_app
```

I get the following output:

```
---Merging InitBranchRevision through FinalBranchRevision into '.':
U     src\main\java\my_app\ApplicationWatcher.java
D     src\main\java\my_app\SomeUtil.Java
D     src\main\java\my_app\dependencies
C     build.gradle
```

How can I prevent the two deleted files above from being removed? I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432344/svn-merge-trunk-into-branch-deleting-files) question, but it doesn't seem to fit this situation because our projects are configured differently.

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

Parallel (to mainline) heavy refactoring in SVN is... well... **The Bad Idea (tm)** - you'll get a lot of headache and "Tree Conflicts" even on technically correct merges later

**Face**

I can't see any correct bit of data in your CLI-merge.

*If* you want to merge changes **from trunk** to branch *and* `InitBranchRevision` is branchpoint *and* `C:\DevTools\workspace\my_app` is WC of your branch *and* your SVN support mergeinfo-data (SVN 1.6+), then, accorging to `svn help merge` (1-st form, part "The 'Feature Branch' Merging Pattern") you have just (in `C:\DevTools\workspace\my_app` directory)

```
svn merge ^/trunk
```

because now you **re-merge revisions from branch to this branch again** (AFAICS): it have to be (at least I expected it) zero-changes or 100% merge-conflicts, but anyway - not requested results